# Typings for factory method that return constructor

Tags: typescript

I have [3d-party lib](https://github.com/featurist/sworm) written with JS. This lib have factory method `db.model()` that return constructor. It looks so:

```
var person = db.model({table: 'people'});

var bob = person({name: 'bob'});

bob.save()
```

Creating objects with `new` not documented, but works too (don't know is it safe or not, but it passes all my tests):

```
var Person = db.model({table: 'people'});

var bob = new Person({name: 'bob'});

bob.save()
```

Also, returned constructor have static methods:

```
person.query('select * from people where id = @id', {id: 1}, function (people) {});
```

The question is how define typings for such case. How define that `db.model()` return constructor, so when I do `const bob = new Person({name: 'bob'})` type of `const bob` would be determine as `Person`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my best guess based on the usage examples you gave:

```
interface DB { 
    model(arg: { table: "people" }): Model<PersonInitParams, Person>;
}
interface Entity { 
    save(): void;
}

type PersonInitParams = { name: string };
interface Person extends Entity { 
    // ...
}
interface Model<IP, E> { 
    (initParams: IP): E;
    new(initParams: IP): E;
    query(query: string, bindParams: {[name: string]: any}, cb: (results: E[]) => void): void;
}
```